# Store class instance for user ES6 Nodejs express passportjs

Tags: node.js, express, ecmascript-6, passport.js, es6-class

I am relatively new to [passportjs](http://passportjs.org/) with express and have a question regarding best practices for the architecture of my application.

First, I want the user to be able to do the following:

- Local Login/Register (username,password)
- Google OAuth

Second, I want to reuse an instance of an [ES6-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) whenever a user makes a call.

Example:

**Class**

```
class ImapConnector { 

  constructor(options) {
     this.options = options;
     this.imap = new IPromise(options);
  }

  connect() {
     return this.imap.connectAsync();
  }

  getBoxes() {
     return this.connect().then(() => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.imap.getBoxes((err, boxes) => {
           err ? reject() : resolve(boxes);
        });
     }));
  }

}
```

**Controller**

```
function getBoxes(req, res) {
   const options = {
      user: req.user.email,
      password: req.user.password,
      host: req.user.email.host,
      port: req.user.email.port,
      tls: true,
      mailbox: 'INBOX'
   };
   const imapConnector = new ImapConnector(options);
   imapConnector.getBoxes().then((boxes) => {
      res.status(200).send(boxes);
   });
}
```

As you can see, the call from the controller is currently creating an instance of the ImapConnector class which is only used for within the controller function's scope. Obviously, a very wasteful approach of memory.

Now, my idea is to create and store the instance in an express user session as the instance is bound to user options such as credentials for imap auth. That way the instance is together with the expiring session.

However, I'm not sure if that is the best and only way.

Thus, my question is: **What is the most reasonable approach for making use of these kind of user-related instances?**

I could also think of persisting these instances in my mongodb (user-schema) and then manually deleting them. Optionally, I would prefer handling the state client-side (e.g. [JWT](https://jwt.io/)).

Thank you in advance!

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: sorry, @NaeemShaikh maybe I wasn't precise: What is the most reasonable approach for making use of user-related instances in an express/node/passport environment?

Comment: I would  store all the options inside the session and create a new ImapConnector on each request

Answer (score 0):

I usually store my instances on the application object (e.g., app.db, app.io). I also have some modules which directly export an instance of a class, then I call module.initialize() when needed (during the server startup).